# How to make time evolution animation in R/ Shiny?

Tags: r, animation, shiny

I'm working on simulation of stochastic differential equation. I want to make a time evolution animation for the obtained trajectories. I tried in R via the `library(anim.plots)` (I couldn't figure out, how to make time evolution animation with `library(animation)`.) I managed to plot two trajectories, but not simultaneously. I tried the merge function, but I didn't obtained the desired result. The code is the following

```
library(Sim.DiffProc)
library(anim.plots)

theta=1
rt=1
at=0.25
K=1000
Tf=3

f<-expression(x*(1-(x/K))^theta*rt)
g<-expression(x*(1-(x/K))^theta*at)
res <- snssde1d(drift=f,diffusion=g,M=2,x0=150,N=500,t0=0, T=Tf)
windows()
tmp1<-anim.plot(time(res),res$X[,1], speed = 500, type="l", col="red", window=1:t, xlim=c(0,Tf), ylim=c(0,K))
tmp2<-anim.plot(time(res),res$X[,2], speed = 500, type="l", col="red", window=1:t, xlim=c(0,Tf), ylim=c(0,K))
myplot<-merge(tmp1,tmp2)
replay(myplot)
```

I also tried to implement it in Shiny. I tried this way

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "time", label="Time:",
              min=0.01, max=10, value=0, step=0.05, animate = animationOptions(50)),
  plotOutput("animation")
)


server<-function(input, output, session)
{
  res<-reactive({
    f<-as.expression(bquote(x*(1-(x/1000))^2*0.5))
    g<-as.expression(bquote(x*(1-(x/1000))^2*0.5))
    snssde1d(drift=f,diffusion=g, M=5, x0=100, T=input$time, N=1000)
  })

  output$animation<-renderPlot({
    plot(res(), plot.type="single",col="lightgrey", xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,1000))
    lines(time(res()),mean(res()), col="red")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Here my problem is that at every step, my program generates a new path. How do I modify my code in order animate the initial paths?

Comment: tweenr plus a lot of useless filler

Comment: You need to make a complete plot for each frame; you can't merge two plots. `gganimate` wraps `animation` for `ggplot2` specifically and makes it pretty simple.

Comment: I haven't used ggplot and their extensions yet. I see that tweenr also needs ggplot.  Is there another method for this? Or can you help me with ggplot?